# PGFPLOTS: insert plots inside axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know how to save `pic`s with a `\tikzset{fig/.pic={code={...`block and know how to insert them into `tikzpictures`. This is very convenient when reusing elements. Unfortunately I do not know how to apply this approach to `pgfplots` elements inside an `axis` environment.

**Desired syntax:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \pic{plot1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \pic{plot1};
    \pic{plot2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where `plot1` and `plot2` are `\addplot` elements to be used repeatedly in different `tikzpictures` in the same document. This could be very useful to create animation-like documents (using the `class=article` option in the `standalone` class the tikzpictures appear on separate pages). I could even create loops.

Sample code to play around with:

```
\documentclass[class=article,tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{%
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
}%

% PLOTS WITH THEIR AXES (NOT THE SYNTAX I WANT)
\tikzset{fig/.pic={code={%
      \begin{axis}
      \addplot [color=blue, domain=0:1] expression {x};
      \addplot [color=red, domain=0:1] expression {1-x};
      \end{axis}  
}}}%

% PLOTS WITHOUT THEIR AXES
% Inserted the scope in the hope that it would help
\tikzset{plot1/.pic={code={%
      \begin{scope}
      \addplot [color=blue, domain=0:1] expression {x};
      \end{scope}
}}}%
\tikzset{plot2/.pic={code={%
      \begin{scope}
      \addplot [color=red, domain=0:1] expression {1-x};
      \end{scope}
}}}%

\begin{document}

% DESIRED OUTPUT BUT NOT DESIRED SYNTAX:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic{fig};
\end{tikzpicture}

% DESIRED SYNTAX BUT WILL FAIL:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \pic{plot1};
    \pic{plot2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to move or transform the plot in any way? Why not use `\newcommand` instead of `pic`?

Comment: That could work... I haven't tried, I was under the impression that it was recommended to you `\tikzset` and `pics`, but I may have misunderstood. Do you want to make it an answer? Thanks.

Comment: You can also use saveboxes.  Also, if you put multiple axis environments in the same tikzpicture they will overlay each other (often used to create a different y axis on the right).

Comment: Thanks John. Indeed, I have used multiple `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, with the `xshift` option to avoid overlap, to display graphs side by side that share a common element like a horizontal line for instance. Are there reasons to prefer saveboxes over newcommands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer, you can set the options and/or have the `\newcommand` in the preamble. Here is my preferred way:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\plotI}{
\addplot [blue, domain=0:1] {x};
}
\newcommand{\plotII}{
\addplot [red, domain=0:1] {1-x};
}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
]
\plotI
\plotII
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with two lines]

**Edit:**

To loop inside `axis`, you need `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and friends - not `foreach` -see manual p.546

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\plotI}[1]{
\addplot [#1, domain=0:1]  {rnd*x};
}
\newcommand{\plotII}{
\addplot [orange, domain=0:1]  {1-x};
}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{red, green, blue}
{\plotI{#1}}
\plotII
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with line and three random plots]

Comment: Thanks hpekristiansen, that's what I was after. Did you name the plots `plotI`, `plotII` instead of `plot1`, `plot2` for any particular reason? While it's a separate question: do you foresee any problem looping over an argument of the new command, e.g. having a parameter inside of `plotI` and plotting the line for a list of values? Thanks again!

Comment: `\newcommand` can not use numbers. Yes - I do see a problem looping inside an axis - see edit.

Comment: Super, thanks so much!